# Exact distinct count in druid

Tags: hadoop, druid

I have loaded data into Druid from Hive and I haven't used any HLL columns.

When i run a `COUNT(DISTINCT mycol)` query in Druid, I do not get exact counts. The counts seem to be close, but do not match with what i have in Hive.

Why could Druid not be giving an exact count even though i haven't mentioned anything about HLL? Alternatively, is there a way to get exact count distincts in Druid?

Found an old post from 2014 regarding same issue https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/druid-development/AMSOVGx5PhQ, am not sure if the current version of Druid supports exact count distincts.

Answer (score 2):

The COUNT(DISTINCT col) aggregation functions by default uses a variant of HyperLogLog, a fast approximate distinct counting algorithm. Druid SQL will switch to exact distinct counts if you set "useApproximateCountDistinct" to "false", either through query context or through broker configuration.( refer http://druid.io/docs/latest/querying/sql.html )

To get actual distinct count set druid.sql.planner.useApproximateCountDistinct to false . ( refer  http://druid.io/docs/latest/configuration/index.html#broker-node-configs ) Also note that there is limitation in exact mode, only one distinct count per query is permitted.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell what is happening without the DDLs and more clues...
I am guessing data got rolled up when indexed by Druid. When you index data with a Granularity other than none, it can get rolled up to the Granularity level.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and in my case it was because of data rollup as Slim mentioned in his answer.

Basically if your data is more granular than your **segmentGranularity** then it will get rolled up automatically. If you set **segmentGranularity** to **None** then it won't get rolled up.

One more thing I observed in my case was, even if I have segment granularity None but if my timestamp and all other columns for two different rows are same then it was getting auto merged into 1 row.

This particular behavior was OK for me as I was also looking for distinct count as you do.